# Logo image in <div> or not in <div> - pros and cons?

Tags: css

I'm using src img to place a logo in the header section. What would the pros and cons be of placing the image in a < div > vs leaving it as a plain ol' img src?

I'm thinking that, for the most part, I should be able to apply the same properties (such as margin, class, ID, etc.) to both. Am I missing something?

Note: I'm not interested in a background-image since I consider the logo content.

Comment: Putting it in a div is usually just a wasted step. The main difference is that a div by default has a display property of block meaning it will bring the element down and screw things up in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr wrapping is always good thing, if you are going to maintain that code for long enough time.

because you can created very targeted css,  show, hide could be easier, round corners and adding text for accessibility will be easier etc..